# python converting strings to floats resulting in error

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I'm trying to convert strings from a txt file with charset: us-ascii.
to np.float64. The data are just decimal numbers (positive and negative).

```
with open(path) as fp:
            data=fp.readlines()
            enr_val = [[np.float(val) for val in line.split()[-1]] for line in data[0:]]
            print(np.shape(enr_val))
```

I'm getting the following errors:

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
and
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'

So, basically the hyphen indicating that the number is negative in e.g. ('-9') and the "." in decimal numbers like (9.2) are causing these problems. I imported unicodedata to get the names of these characters:

```
print(*map(unicodedata.name, data[0].split()[-1][0]))
```

and got the following result: 
'.' is Full stop
and '-' is HYPHEN-MINUS

I don't understand what's causing the problem and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure that the val are all convertible to float?

Comment: yes. I just printed some values and here are the results:
0.0
0.0
1
1
0.000000
1.000000
0.000000
-10.0
10.0
1
1
4.597581
0.000000
0.000000

Comment: You're converting individual characters. `line.split()[-1]` is a single string containing (for example) `'0.000000'`. When you do `for val in line.split()[-1]`, each `val` value is a single character from that string. The second character is a decimal point. Did you maybe mean to use `line.split()[:-1]`?

Comment: No. Each line contains several columns and I only want to read the last column. So, each val in line.split()[-1] points to the last column which is a string.